# How to install texlive 2011?

Tags: installation, latex

i'm not quite sure whether the problem with my texlive installation isn't sitting in front of the computer but i just cannot get it to work.

The first thing I did was download the installer from the texlive homepage, run it and try the installation with all the options preselected.

When I tried to install "gummi" (latex editor) from its ppa afterwards it was telling me it had some uninstalled dependencies (mostly texlive 2009 packages from the ubuntu repositories).

Then I went back and started reading some more on the installation topic and there was a vague mentioning of having to set PATH for the installation. I couldn't figure out how to do that so I found the option in the installer "create symlinks in standard directories" which I figured was an automated option of the PATH settings.

Now I tried to install gummi once more and it still came back with all the lacking dependencies. I figured I'd try just installing it but now i'm sitting there with a bowl of nothing - even the installation of 13 of the packages from the repositories failed with errors, for example:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-extra:
 texlive-latex-extra depends on texlive-pictures (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-pictures is not configured yet.
 texlive-latex-extra depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
```

Now i'm wondering where I went wrong and whether there is somebody who could give me a fool-proof explanation on how to install the 2011 texlive. Unfortunately I couldn't find a good explanation by raiding google.

Thanks hell of a lot in advance for any help on those matters
Best regards

Comment: Seems that you question is how to install TeX Live 2011 from upstream and use it together with gummi in a ppa. You might want to make this clearer, e.g. by changing the name of the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use texlive 2011, check [this blog](http://alexkrispin.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/update-a-script-to-automate-the-installation-of-texlive-2011-on-ubuntu/) which contains a script to automate the installation on Ubuntu. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the link - i'll try to install it that way. But why "if you really want to use texlive 2011"? Is there a problem with the newest version? I just thought using the up to date packages would be better than using the older ones in the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Well, I had the same thoughts about it. I went through installing texlive 2011 because of the same idea you have. I moved back to the texlive from the ubuntu repos and compared results. If you really do not have any problems with the standard-repos, I would use them because they are easier to install and maintain.